malit keyboard darkmode not working
I am using a Kubuntu 24.04.1 system and have installed Malit Keyboard, but it is not properly themed at all. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Does this command help? gsettings set org.maliit.keyboard.maliit theme BreezeDark

no there is no change
